# Handling default slot on custom component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Iam stugging on a problem to handle default slots with `render()` function.

I have two components, one that passes a string value `innerHTML` to my custom Component `MySub`. In `MySub` i wants to use the default slot to do further stuff with it.

My Parent:

```
import { defineComponent, h, VNode } from "vue";
import MySub from "./mySub.ts"

export default defineComponent({
  render() {
    return h(MySub, {}, 'innerHTML')
  }
})
```

My Sub:

```
import { defineComponent, h, VNode } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.$slots.default && this.$slots.default()[0]) this.value = <string>this.$slots.default()[0].children
  },
  render() {
    return h('div', {}, [this.value + ' "here my added Stuff"'])
  }
})
```

Now to my problem: When i code it like this (above or link below), i get a warning calls: `Non-function value encountered for default slot. Prefer function slots for better performance.` I know whats todo to get rid of these message and why its exists. Just add a function call to the value in my `MyParent` `return h(MySub, {}, () => 'innerHTML')`.

But when i do this, it get the following message: `Slot "default" invoked outside of the render function: this will not track dependencies used in the slot. Invoke the slot function inside the render function instead.` Also here, i know what the message wants to tell me, but i cant find a why to handle these problem.

I hope, i could explain my problem clear enough and somebody know what i can do.

[Here is an Playground Example that reproduce exactly my problem.](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know its the correct way to reply my own question, but i found and resolved the problem...

The problem isnt occur in the parent component. You always should call default slots within a function call like: `() => 'innerHTML'` for better performance (like the warn message is calling) cause to not render it, when its empty.

So i have to search for the problem in the child...

And the problem was the function `mounted()`

```
m̶o̶u̶n̶t̶e̶d̶(̶)̶ ̶{̶
  i̶f̶ ̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶$̶s̶l̶o̶t̶s̶.̶d̶e̶f̶a̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶&̶&̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶$̶s̶l̶o̶t̶s̶.̶d̶e̶f̶a̶u̶l̶t̶(̶)̶[̶0̶]̶)̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶$̶s̶l̶o̶t̶s̶.̶d̶e̶f̶a̶u̶l̶t̶(̶)̶[̶0̶]̶.̶c̶h̶i̶l̶d̶r̶e̶n̶
}̶,̶
```

In the `render()` function, i used `this.value` that is declared outside in the `data()` and assigned in the `mounted()`. So i just had to put it inside like below:

```
getDefaultSlotValue() {
  if (this.$slots.default && this.$slots.default()[0]) this.value = <string>this.$slots.default()[0].children
},
render() {
  return h('div', {}, [this.getDefaultSlotValue() + ' "here my added Stuff"'])
}
```

Iam not sure, but the problem seems to be no problem, when you call the `MySub` directly (to see in `App.vue`), cause the `mounted()` is normally called after rendering. But i dont know, whats vue exactly doing under the hood.

[Here an working Playground example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)